# Creating a cross-browser fixed height scrollable display: table-row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a container, of height 80% of the page height, which has a fixed height header and footer with a content pane that stretches to fit the rest of the available space.

I've tried to use display: table with the following layout:

```
<body>
<div class="ticket">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

With these styles

```
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .ticket {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 80%;
    display: table;
  }

  .header {
    background: blue;
    height: 36px;
    display: table-row;
  }

  .body {
    background: orange;
    display: table-row;
  }

  .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .content {
    height: 600px;
  }

  .footer {
    background: green;
    height: 72px;
    display: table-row;
  }
```

In Chrome this gives me a scrollable middle panel that grows with the height of the container:
[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't work in IE8 or Firefox, the '.body' div stretches to fit the '.content'.

Is there a way to do this that will work cross browser, and IE8+?

Comment: You might need to use jquery to get it to work in older browsers. - This might be your problem: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp - The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", and "table-row-group" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox and/or http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Those are the ways to get it, but none of them works on IE 8.
You must use JS